# Can the boundary of a subset be open?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ a subset of $X$. Can $\partial A$ be an open subset of $X$?

Of course the answer is no if $A$ were closed; that is $\partial A\subset A$, because in this case we would have $int(\partial A)\subset int(A)$ hence by definition of $\partial A$ no point of $\partial A$ can be in $int(\partial A)$ because in that case we would have a point in $\partial A$ which is also in $int(A)$, something that is not allowed.

Now what if $A$ is not closed, that is there  are boundary points in $X$ to $A$ that are not contained in $A$?

Comment: Hint: Suppose $A$ is dense but has empty interior. What happens?
Can you find an example of this particular situation?

Comment: The only example given other than the trivial discrete case is your above condition, so apart from this situation we can say that the boundary is never open ?

Comment: If $X$ is connected then the only cases in which $\partial A$ is open are $\partial A=X$ (i.e. $A$ is dense with empty interior) and $\partial A=\emptyset$ (i.e. $A$ open and closed, which implies $A=\emptyset$ or $A=X$).

Comment: There are no other possibilities since $\partial A$ would have to be both open and closed.

Comment: If $A$ is open, then $\partial A$ cannot have any interior points. Any neighborhood $U$ around a point $x\in\partial A$ intersects $A$ and $A\cap\partial A$ are disjoint, so $U\not\subseteq\partial A$. So if $\partial A$ is open, then $A$ cannot be open and $X$ must be disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the [boundary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)) $\partial A$ is defined to be $\overline A - \operatorname{int}(A) = \overline A \cap \operatorname{int}(A)^c$. Since $\operatorname{int}(A)$ is open, its complement is closed. Hence the boundary of any set is an intersection of closed sets, which is closed.

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, I haven't addressed your question. As I'm sure you're aware, sets can be both open and closed in a topological space. In fact, there are always at least two sets that are both open and closed: the entire space and the empty set. With this in mind, consider $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: What is the relationship between this and the question?

Comment: While this is true, the boundary can be open and closed at the same time. These are not mutually exclusive properties.

Comment: @Mizar, you're correct that I do not address the question. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a discrete space, then every subset of $X$ is open. In particular, every boundary of every subspace is open.

Also, viewing $\Bbb Q$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R$ equipped with the classical topology, we have
$$
\partial\Bbb Q=\bar{\Bbb Q}\setminus\Bbb Q^\circ=\Bbb R\setminus\varnothing=\Bbb R
$$

Answer (score 1):

It can be. Take for instance the topology $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{P}(X)$.

Comment: Dear @Darth Geek  I did not understand your notation.

Comment: @palio $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is the set of all subsets of $X$, so in this case, all subsets of $X$ are open. This can happen, for instance when you induce the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: you mean the descrete topology?

Comment: @palio In this case, when you induce the metric topology of $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{Z}$ you get the discrete topology, yes, but in other examples it could not be so.

Comment: I've always heard the discrete topology defined as the topology where every subset is open.

Comment: @JHance Yes, but only for discrete spaces (or at least that's what I've been taught)

Comment: Isn't this a bit of a degenerate example, since $\partial A = \emptyset$ (which is open but uninteresting) for every $A \subset X$.  Additionally, any $A$ that's both open and closed satisfies this property.

Comment: Well. it's certainly trivial, but trivial counterexamples are still counterexamples.